# Reversing a varray in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So i have a varray that contains 20 elements for example numbers from 1 to 20 and i want to reverse that order so the varray becomes 20 to 1 
Every time i trie to do that the values of the table changes.

Comment: Show us the code that you tried.

Answer (score 1):

you can `REVERSE` keyword while looping through the collection. some thing like

```
 declare
    begin
      for k in reverse 1..20  loop 
        dbms_output.put_line(k);
        end loop;
      end;
```